# Price.phtml and product.phtml is not working on my other store but working in may other store anyone can help?

Tags: product, price

[image: CAN ANYONE HELP ME WITH THIS ISSUE]

I have 2 stores, they have the same in price.phtml and product.phtml. But it is not working on my other store, can anyone help me ?

Comment: Are the product types identical? Can you try duplicating the product that works on your other store?